# Undefined reference using SLRE lib

Tags: c

I am using the SLRE (http://slre.sourceforge.net/) for doing REGEX checking in a C program.
I am including the headerfile and then I do following:

```
void checkRegex() {
    struct slre slre;
    struct cap captures[4+1];

    if(!slre_compile(&slre, "regularexpression") {
        printf("error");
    }
}
```

I am doing the compiling with that command: `gcc example1.c -o test.cgi -L. -lconfig` and I get that error: `example1.c:(.text+0x1af3): undefined reference to 'slre_compile'`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, your linking the correct library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the library and it consists of slre.c and slre.h so you probably compile it like

```
gcc slre.c -o slre.o -c
gcc example1.c slre.o -o test.cgi -L -lconfig
```

Comment: Well, that's the problem if you always use Visual Studio and stop thinking when you use other stuff ^^, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include the header file **and** include the **slre.c** in your program. SLRE isn't a "header only" library.

---

Edit: Just saw that compile line in your answer. You can use this one-liner:

```
gcc example1.c slre.c -o test.cgi -L. -lconfig
```

However, this will (re)compile SLRE every time. To save some compile time, you should cache the compiled SLRE using the lines in Adrian's answer.

Comment: I have both files at the right position, so it should work when the headerfile is included, right?

Comment: You'll have to tell the compiler to use both c files (yours and **slre.c**). For GCC you can do it the way Adrian suggests. As an alternative, just list/add **slre.c** the way you added your own c file.